# NodeJS Multiplexing Terminal?

Tags: node.js, io

Here's my issue. I'm outputting directly to console and also getting user input via the terminal. Sometimes, the user is typing a thing and then the text they were typing gets messed up when the console outputs something. It doesn't break the program, it's just annoying.

I looked at ncurses in the npm catalog, but it seems pretty complicated. All I want is to print stuff to the screen without disrupting user input.

Any help, and I do mean any help, is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading from the terminal? If you're doing it in "raw" mode where you get input for each character (or each few characters), then when you get a character, set an "output inhibit" flag and also set a timeout that will clear the flag when the user has stopped typing for a bit. Whatever does your output needs to check the flag and hold off if it's set.

Alternatively, if the user is typing line-by-line, you could set the flag on each character and then clear it (and simply flush your output) when they enter a newline.

If the terminal is in "cooked" mode (your code doesn't see anything until the user types a newline) there's really little you can unless you bite the ncurses bullet.

Comment: yeah, I guess curses is just gonna have to work. thanks for your help.